# Turn off vibration inside my app

Tags: android, android-vibration

I'm developing an app and need to completely turn off vibration alerts when my app is running. For example if an call comes in while my app is open I don't want to have the vibration alert, the same with emails and anyother notification.

So I've been googling around for a while and found this:

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

The problem is that this method is deprecated. And I can't find an other way of doing this.

The minSdkVersion = 9 and targetSdkVersion = 17.

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible. Any app that wants to can interact with the unfortunately-named `Vibrator` system service and vibrate the device, for devices that have a vibration motor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [AudioManager RingerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29)

It should now be

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```